# NTP server time drifting

Tags: ntp, time

We currently do not have NTP (Network Time Protocol) appliance in our environment. So we are using one of server as NTP master server and remaining servers are synced with this using NTP port. Is there any low cost option other than using NTP appliance to avoid this time drift in NTP master server or any tricks to reduce this drift?

Answer (score 3):

Your NTP server can itself sync it's own clock over the internet with a public NTP server. I'd suggest a server address, but the best options depend on where you are in the world.

Answer (score 2):

You can sync your master NTP server over the internet with one of the many public NTP servers, such as the ones provided by http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/ (as long as you're in Europe or North America and not in Africa or South America you're well-served)

Since GPS is essentially a very accurate clock signal you can hook up a [GPS receiver](https://serverfault.com/questions/604397) or build one from a raspberry Pi in just  [over 5 minutes](http://ava.upuaut.net/?p=726)...